# Gives ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 on Oracle select statement from on .net application

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
string vDate="2017/06/08";
OracleCommand cmd= new OracleCommand();
OracleParamater pDate= new OracleParameter("pDate",OracleDbType.Varchar2);
pDate.Direction=ParameterDirection.Input;
pDate.Value= vDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pDate);
cmd.CommandText="select * from testtable where joinDate<=to_date(:pDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD')";
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
DataSet ds= new DataSet();
OracleDataAdapter adp= new OracleDataAdapter(); //Please assume that db is connected successfully.
adp.fill(ds);
```

joinDate type is of Date.

When application execute the query it is giving ora-01841 error. I tried with  OracleDBType.Date too, assigning vDate as DateTime type. How do I fix this issue?

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the code to add the parameter to the cmd object?

Comment: @flaZer  I have updated the question.

Comment: Out on a limb here... perhaps in the DB, there are NULL values for JOINDATE and there you find the real issue?  Because otherwise I don't see an issue with your code.

Comment: "select * from testtable where nvl(joinDate,to_date(''1900/01/01'', 'YYYY/MM/DD'))<=to_date(:pDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD')" - or maybe just a simple NULL check on JOINDATE?

Comment: I'm also a bit rusty on Oracle dates... perhaps you can even compare it to a Zero... **where joinDate = 0 or joinDate<=to_date(:pDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD')**. Fairly certain (but not completely!) the SQL when encountering the 1st condition, won't attempt to check the 2nd condition, but again, not completely certain...

Comment: As a test of your assumption that the parameter causes the problem, try the opposite: remove the parameter from the query and replace it with a literal value of `'2017/06/08'`.  Maybe it's something completely different that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `new OracleParameter("pDate",OracleDbType.Varchar2)` it should be `OracleParameter("pDate",OracleDbType.date);`

Comment: I tried keeping OracleDbType.date as well. I think pDate is a parameter so  can be send as string and convert to_date on query.

Comment: If I try with OracleDbType Date, it's giving me Invalid Number error msg

Answer (score 0):

You should better use it like this:

```
DateTime vDate = new DateTime(2017, 6, 8);
OracleCommand cmd= new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText="select * from testtable where joinDate <= :pDate";
OracleParamater pDate= new OracleParameter("pDate",OracleDbType.Date);
pDate.Direction=ParameterDirection.Input;
pDate.Value= vDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pDate);
```

Comment: I am getting ORA-01858: a non numberic character was found where numeric was expected. I tried hardcoding the value on query on c# code, its working fine there.

Comment: Is joinDate really `DATE`? Carefully review your code for typos.

Comment: Yes It is DATE.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other parameters, make sure they are in right order.